# Get column index by Column header in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How to get the `Column` index or `Column.DisplayIndex` from its `Column Header` in `WPF` `DataGrid`?

I know the `Column Header`, want to get `column index`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you could use `DisplayIndex` (be aware this will change if columns are resorted)

```
var index = dataGrid.Columns.Single(c => c.Header.ToString() == "HeaderName").DisplayIndex;
```

edited: thanks for suggestion from @AnHX

Comment: Look at AnHx post for a bugfix. This code compares references no values.

Answer (score 4):

Look like "paul" have an small error. Here is my code:

```
var index = dataGrid.Columns.Single(c => c.Header.ToString() == "HeaderName").DisplayIndex;
```