# WPF: get all list of specified controls from DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have main `DataGrid` for displaying a list of documents.
This `MainGrid` has `DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate` specified in `XAML`.

This `DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate` contains one more (inner or nested) `DataGrid`s.

So each row of `MainGrid` contains `DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate` with inner `DataGrid`.

I need to get list of all inner (nested) `DataGrid`s having only the `MainGrid` reference.
I've tried Visual/Logil Tree helpers, but both returns nothing for GetChildren calls...

What is the way to get nested `DataGrid` from `DataGrid.RowDetails`?

Repro steps:
1) Create Windows Desktop -> WPF Application (empty) in Visual Studio 2013 or higher
2) Use code samples below:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ExampleNestedGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ToolBar Grid.Row="0" Header="Action:">
            <Button x:Name="RefreshBtn" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">Refresh</Button>
        </ToolBar>

        <DataGrid x:Name="MainGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Documents}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Number, Mode=OneWay}" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <DataGrid x:Name="NestedGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding LinkedEmployees}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id, Mode=OneWay}" Width="150"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" Width="150"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Status, Mode=OneWay}" Width="150"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ExampleNestedGrid
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new DisplayViewModel(MainGrid);
        }
    }

    public class DisplayViewModel : PropertyBase
    {
        private DataGrid MainGrid;

        public DisplayViewModel(DataGrid MainGrid) 
        {
            this.MainGrid = MainGrid;

            Documents = new ObservableCollection<Document>();
            LinkedEmployee empl1 = new LinkedEmployee("1", "Ben");
            LinkedEmployee empl2 = new LinkedEmployee("2", "John");

            Document doc = new Document("first", "111");
            doc.LinkedEmployees.Add(empl1);
            doc.LinkedEmployees.Add(empl2);

            Documents.Add(doc);

            RefreshCommand = new RefreshCommand(Documents, MainGrid);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
        public ICommand RefreshCommand { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class LinkedEmployee : PropertyBase
    {
        public LinkedEmployee(string id, string name)
        {
            _id = id;
            _name = name;
        }

        public void Update(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        private string _id;
        private string _name;
        private bool _status;

        public bool Status 
        {
            get { return _status; }
            set
            {
                _status = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set
            {
                _id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Document : PropertyBase
    {
        public Document(string name, string number)
        {
            _name = name;
            _number = number;

            LinkedEmployees = new ObservableCollection<LinkedEmployee>();
        }

        public void Update(string number)
        {
            Number = number;
        }

        private string _name;
        private string _number;

        public virtual string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public virtual string Number
        {
            get { return _number; }
            set
            {
                _number = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<LinkedEmployee> LinkedEmployees { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class PropertyBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region public properties
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        #endregion

        #region protected methods
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string caller = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

RefreshCommand.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace ExampleNestedGrid
{
    public class RefreshCommand : ICommand
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Document> Documents;
        private System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid MainGrid;

        #region public methods
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
        #endregion

        #region public methods

        public RefreshCommand(ObservableCollection<Document> Documents, System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid MainGrid)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.Documents = Documents;
            this.MainGrid = MainGrid;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            Documents.First().LinkedEmployees.First().Status = !Documents.First().LinkedEmployees.First().Status;

            ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Documents);
            view.Filter = (item) => item != null;

            MainGrid.ItemsSource = view;

            var childGrids = FindVisualChildren<DataGrid>(MainGrid);
            foreach (DataGrid childGrid in childGrids)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(childGrid.Name);
            }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return Documents != null && MainGrid != null;
        }
        #endregion

        private static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            if (depObj != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
                {
                    DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                    if (child != null && child is T)
                    {
                        yield return (T)child;
                    }

                    foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                    {
                        yield return childOfChild;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3) Start application. Click on first row. Row Details should expand.

4) Sort main row by first column

5) Sort row details by second column

6) Click refresh button

7) Check that sorting indicator disappeared.

8) Check that no message box appeared that should fire about found nested data grids.
[image]

Comment: You can only get a reference to a currently visible element in the RowDetailsTemplate. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to get all visible nested grids and update them with sort descriptions

Comment: When exactly do you need to do this?

Comment: User tries to filter rows by some criteria, after filter is applied, sorting for nested grids is reseted to default (first column). So I want to at least try to update sort description for each visible nested DataGrid... `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only get a reference to a currently visible element in the `RowDetailsTemplate`. Try this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var childGrids = FindVisualChildren<DataGrid>(MainGrid);
    foreach (DataGrid childGrid in childGrids)
    {
        //...
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Call the `UpdateLayout()` method of the `DataGrid` if you reset its `ItemsSource`. This implementation of the `Execute` method of the command works for me if I select a row in the parent `DataGrid` and click on the "Refresh" button:

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    Documents.First().LinkedEmployees.First().Status = !Documents.First().LinkedEmployees.First().Status;

    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Documents);
    view.Filter = (item) => item != null;

    MainGrid.ItemsSource = view;
    MainGrid.UpdateLayout();

    List<DataGrid> childGrids = new List<DataGrid>();
    foreach (var item in MainGrid.Items)
    {
        var container = MainGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
        if (container != null)
        {
            childGrids.AddRange(FindVisualChildren<DataGrid>(container));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But as I said, I've already tried this approach too. It seems like RowDetails are not treated like child container control...

Comment: It certainly works for me. Make sure that the details are actually visible by the time the Button_Click event handler above is called.

Comment: It shows nothing at all. You should always provide a minimal repo when you ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Okay. it will take some time. Thanks

Comment: I've updated description with full code for reproduce

Comment: But sorting in nested grid now is not preserved at all... and any changes to sortdescriptions of the view does not saved on any changes to entities inside grid

Comment: Solution for sorting found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071346/get-column-index-by-column-header-in-wpf-datagrid